# Hybris with wro4j not pulling in addon js files

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, wro4j

When using wro4j for minification in Hyrbis addon js files are not being added to the generated minified/concatenated output (/wro/addons_responsive.js) OOTB addons are being pulled in however third party addons are not.

I've added their path to the wro.xml for the specific storefront and have wro4jconfigscan.*addon*=true property in the relevant addon project.properties.template file.

I can't quite see which part of the puzzle I'm missing.. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure, you have added the below properties in your **project.properties** of your addon

```
<your>storefront.wro4jconfigscan.<your>addon=true
<your>addon.javascript.paths.responsive=/responsive/common/js/<your>addon.js;/responsive/common/js/<your>addon2.js
<your>aaddon.css.paths.responsive=/responsive/common/css/<your>addon.css;/responsive/common/css/<your>addon2.css
```

During the build, above js & css files will be added to your **wro_addon.xml** file under storefront resource folder.

---

Another way is to add your addon css/js path directly to `${ext.YOURstorefront.path}/wro_addons_template.xml`, which used to create `wro_addon.xml` while building the platform.

Like

```
<groups xmlns="http://www.isdc.ro/wro" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.isdc.ro/wro wro.xsd">
    <group name="addons_responsive">
        <js>/_ui/addons/b2bacceleratoraddon/responsive/common/js/acc.checkoutsummary.js</js>
        <js>/_ui/addons/customaddon/responsive/common/js/acc.customaddon.js</js>
        <css>/_ui/addons/customaddon/responsive/common/css/customaddon.css</css>

    </group>
</groups>
```